# Url rewrite with action and parameters

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, yii-url-manager

current url is below ( yii default rule )

```
www.xyz.com/module/controller/action/slug-name
```

**slug-name** is one parameter that will be come from database

I need to rewrite url like below

```
www.xyz.com/module/controller/slug-name/action
```

How can I do this? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a url-manager rule like this:

```
'profile/admin/<slug>/test' => 'profile/admin/test'
```

Now, suppose I have a `profile` module. I have `adminController` controller in this module and have defined a `actionTest` in this controller. Signature of `actionTest` should be like this:

```
public function actionTest($slug){}
```